# fit LogisticRegression model on test data get the same score as fit on train data

Tags: scikit-learn, train-test-split

I fit LogisticRegression model on train data  checked the score on test and get

> test_score 0.802083

afterward ,Out of curiosity,
I fit the model  on tets and  checked the score on test and somehow get the same test score.

why?

I am using diabitis data

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database?select=diabetes.csv

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression



diab_cols = ['Pregnancies', 'Insulin', 'BMI','Glucose','BloodPressure','DiabetesPedigreeFunction'] 
X = df[diab_cols]# Features 
y = df.Outcome # Target variable 




X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
    test_size=0.25, 
    random_state=0)




model = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)  
 
model_test = LogisticRegression().fit( X_test, y_test)  



print("test_score",model.score(X_test,y_test))
print("test_score",model_test.score(X_test,y_test))
```

Comment: it would be helpful to checkout dataset, maybe there is data leakage in your training data

Comment: I edited the quiestion and added link to the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your test data is a "perfect" representation of training set.

**One possibility** is the model created on both training and test set having similar weights. You can verify the weights of the two `LogisticRegression` models.

*e.g.,*

```
print(model.coef_[0])
print(model_test.coef_[0])
```

If the weights of the models are different, **second possibility** is that the classification points always lie on the same side of the threshold (default `0.5`) and therefore are classified same in both models, keeping the score same. You can check the confidence level of the model for all the test classification by calling the `decision_function()` method.

*e.g.,*

```
model.decision_function(x_test)
model_test.decision_function(x_test)
```

Comment: model.coef_ and decision_function gave me different results!  so i split the data again with random_state=10 instaed of 0 and....I got diffrnet score!!   as yo said :" test data is a "perfect" representation of training set"    .   (I edited the quiestion and added  the link to the file)